# Doctrine Entity ordering policy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi everyone this is my first question!

I would like to have an Entity, with a field that indicates order, say EntityInstance1 with order 1, EntityInstance2 with order 2, EntityInstance3 with order 3... etc. Then for example I want to create a new instance, and give it order 2. So the result would be EntityInstance1 with order 1, EntityInstance4 with order 2, EntityInstance2 with order 3 and Entity Instance3 with order 4. An then let's say that I delete EntityInstance1, so I'll have EntityInstance4 with order 1, EntityInstance2 with order 2, EntityInstance3 with order 3. How could be this achieved??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working! Using lifecycle events and bulk updates!

Here's my entity:

```
namespace LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Meeting
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\MeetingRepository")
 */
class Meeting {
    /* ***************************************************************************************/
    /* Properties ****************************************************************************/
    /* ***************************************************************************************/

    // Mapped

    /**
     *
     * @var integer @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     *      @ORM\Id
     *      @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var string @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="El campo nombre es obligatorio")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer @ORM\Column(name="production_order", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $productionOrder;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer @ORM\Column(name="staging_order", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $stagingOrder;

    /**
     *
     * @var boolean @ORM\Column(name="production_enabled", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $productionEnabled;

    /**
     *
     * @var boolean @ORM\Column(name="staging_enabled", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $stagingEnabled;

    /* ***************************************************************************************/
    /* Getters & Setters *********************************************************************/
    /* ***************************************************************************************/

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name          
     * @return Meeting
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set productionOrder
     *
     * @param integer $productionOrder          
     * @return Meeting
     */
    public function setProductionOrder($productionOrder) {
        $this->productionOrder = $productionOrder;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get productionOrder
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getProductionOrder() {
        return $this->productionOrder;
    }

    /**
     * Set stagingOrder
     *
     * @param integer $stagingOrder         
     * @return Meeting
     */
    public function setStagingOrder($stagingOrder) {
        $this->stagingOrder = $stagingOrder;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get stagingOrder
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStagingOrder() {
        return $this->stagingOrder;
    }

    /**
     * Set productionEnabled
     *
     * @param boolean $productionEnabled            
     * @return Meeting
     */
    public function setProductionEnabled($productionEnabled) {
        $this->productionEnabled = $productionEnabled;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get productionEnabled
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getProductionEnabled() {
        return $this->productionEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Set stagingEnabled
     *
     * @param boolean $stagingEnabled           
     * @return Meeting
     */
    public function setStagingEnabled($stagingEnabled) {
        $this->stagingEnabled = $stagingEnabled;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get stagingEnabled
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getStagingEnabled() {
        return $this->stagingEnabled;
    }

    /* ***************************************************************************************/
    /* Other Methods *************************************************************************/
    /* ***************************************************************************************/
}
```

Then, here is the EventListener

```
namespace LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\Meeting;

class MeetingIndexerSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            'prePersist',
            'preUpdate',
            'postRemove'
        );
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if($entity instanceof Meeting) {
            $stagingOrder = $entity->getStagingOrder(); 
            if(isset($stagingOrder)) {
                $dql = "UPDATE LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\Meeting
                        m set m.stagingOrder = m.stagingOrder + 1
                        WHERE m.stagingOrder >= $stagingOrder";

                $entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
            }

            $productionOrder = $entity->getProductionOrder();
            if(isset($productionOrder)) {
                $dql = "UPDATE LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\Meeting
                        m set m.productionOrder = m.productionOrder + 1
                        WHERE m.productionOrder >= $productionOrder";

                $entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
            }
        }
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if($entity instanceof Meeting) {
            if($args->hasChangedField('stagingOrder')) {
                if($args->getNewValue('stagingOrder') > $args->getOldValue('stagingOrder')) {
                    $dql = 'UPDATE LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\Meeting
                            m set m.stagingOrder = m.stagingOrder - 1
                            WHERE m.stagingOrder > ' . $args->getOldValue('stagingOrder') .
                            ' AND m.stagingOrder <= ' . $args->getNewValue('stagingOrder');

                    $entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
                }

                if($args->getNewValue('stagingOrder') < $args->getOldValue('stagingOrder')) {
                    $dql = 'UPDATE LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\Meeting
                            m set m.stagingOrder = m.stagingOrder + 1
                            WHERE m.stagingOrder >= ' . $args->getNewValue('stagingOrder') .
                            ' AND m.stagingOrder < ' . $args->getOldValue('stagingOrder');

                    $entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
                }
            }

            if($args->hasChangedField('productionOrder')) {
                if($args->getNewValue('productionOrder') > $args->getOldValue('productionOrder')) {
                    $dql = 'UPDATE LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\Meeting
                            m set m.productionOrder = m.productionOrder - 1
                            WHERE m.productionOrder > ' . $args->getOldValue('productionOrder') .
                            ' AND m.productionOrder <= ' . $args->getNewValue('productionOrder');

                    $entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
                }

                if($args->getNewValue('productionOrder') < $args->getOldValue('productionOrder')) {
                    $dql = 'UPDATE LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\Meeting
                            m set m.productionOrder = m.productionOrder + 1
                            WHERE m.productionOrder >= ' . $args->getNewValue('productionOrder') .
                            ' AND m.productionOrder < ' . $args->getOldValue('productionOrder');

                    $entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if($entity instanceof Meeting) {
            $stagingOrder = $entity->getStagingOrder(); 
            if(isset($stagingOrder)) {
                $dql = "UPDATE LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\Meeting
                        m set m.stagingOrder = m.stagingOrder - 1
                        WHERE m.stagingOrder > $stagingOrder";

                $entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
            }

            $productionOrder = $entity->getProductionOrder();
            if(isset($productionOrder)) {
                $dql = "UPDATE LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\Entity\Meeting
                        m set m.productionOrder = m.productionOrder - 1
                        WHERE m.productionOrder > $productionOrder";

                $entityManager->createQuery($dql)->execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, in the config file:

```
services:
    meeting.indexer_suscriber:
        class: LuchoNat\Icna\Website\BackendBundle\EventListener\MeetingIndexerSubscriber
        tags:
             - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

It works!!!

I used [Symfony 2: How to Register Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) and [Doctrine 2: Events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) documentation!

Comment: good work, well done. This is much more efficient than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I really don't know why anybody would do something like that, but ok, it's realizeable. Let's think logical.
1) You have multiple instances of the same object => means you have a collection of object
2) A Collection has some kind of iterator
3) You can use the iterator to iterate over the list and update the instances orders.

So the easiest, but most expensive way to realize your vision is:

```
$objectCollection = $this -> get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager') -> getRepository('YOUR_ENTITY') -> findBy(array(),array('order','asc'));
$iterator = $objectCollection -> getArrayIterator();
$i = 1;
while($object = $iterator -> next()){
    $object -> setOrder($i);
    $i++;
}
$this -> get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager') -> flush();
```

Note: order can not be used as a property name. So you need another name and change it in the code sample, too.

Comment: I guess that would be very inefficient... what i'm trying to do is something like a news manager for a website, and what i need to have is a simple way to alter the order (arbitrary order) in which these news are shown.

Comment: Think I'm going to solve it using lifecycle events and doctrine bulk update queries!